# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table orderTime has no column named product_price

Tags: android, database, model-view-controller, android-sqlite

I have gone trough all the posts related to this problem on stack overflow but not able to get any solution that worked out. I am using sqlite datebase in android to store data but each time I tried it throws an error that table do not have such column.

// code for database class

```
public class demo extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "orderTimeManager";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_ORDER = "orderTime";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String PRODUCT_ID = "product_id";
    private static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "product_name";
    private static final String PRODUCT_DETAIL = "product_detail";
    private static final String PRODUCT_TYPE = "product_type";
    private static final String PRODUCT_PRICE = "product_price";


    public demo(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_ORDER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ORDER + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT," + PRODUCT_DETAIL + " TEXT,"
                + PRODUCT_TYPE + " TEXT,"
                + PRODUCT_PRICE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ORDER_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ORDER);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    // Adding new order
    public void addOrder(ProductModel object) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // Contact Name
        values.put(PRODUCT_NAME, object.getProductName()); // Contact Phone Number
        values.put(PRODUCT_DETAIL, object.getProductDetail());
        values.put(PRODUCT_TYPE, object.getProductType());
        values.put(PRODUCT_PRICE, object.getProductType());


        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_ORDER, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }





     // Getting All order

       public List<ProductModel> getAllOrders() {
        List<ProductModel> orderList = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ORDER;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ProductModel object = new ProductModel();
                object.setProductId(cursor.getString(0));

                object.setProductName((cursor.getString(1)));
                object.setProductDetail(cursor.getString(2));
                object.setProductType(cursor.getString(3));
                object.setProductPrice(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
                // Adding contact to list
                orderList.add(object);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return orderList;
    }
```

// call database in another class to add data

```
    JSONObject ob1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    {
                        String productId = ob1.getString("pkproductId");
                        String productName = ob1.getString("name");
                        String productType = ob1.getString("productType");
                        String productPrice = ob1.getString("price");
                        String productDetails = ob1.getString("details");


                        Log.d(TAG, "Inserting");
                        db.addOrder(new ProductModel(productName,productDetails,productType,Integer.parseInt(productPrice)));
 }



  // Product Model 


      public ProductModel( String productName, String productDetail, String productType, int productPrice) {
    this.productId = productId;
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productDetail = productDetail;
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
    this.productType = productType;
}
```

Comment: try to change the DATABASE_VERSION = 1; to 2: and then uninstall your app and install it again. Hope this helps

Comment: use String productPrice in ProductModel and remove Integer.parseInt( from db.addOrder. because your database having TEXT datatype

Comment: did you changed your table structure after running your app?. Is so then your onCreate will not run unless you uninstall/reinstall your app. Another option is to use `onUpgrade()` method

Comment: please check my answer below

Comment: post your full logcat/stacktrace. Their must be some other issue. Or try cleaning and rebuilding your project and uninstall the old apk and install it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try step by step

1) try to change the DATABASE_VERSION = 1; to 2: and then install it again

2) use String productPrice in ProductModel and remove `Integer.parseInt(` from `db.addOrder`. because your database having TEXT datatype

3) change this line

```
values.put(PRODUCT_TYPE, object.getProductType());
values.put(PRODUCT_PRICE, object.getProductPrice());
```

hope it helps you. if this doesn't help feel free to ask the problem

Comment: App uninstall isn't necessary if you change db version.

Comment: i think only `clear data` should have been enough @fluffyBatman , ain't it?

Comment: @Nilabja Changing db version, uninstall and install app and clear data all have same effect here. All of them trigger a new `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` call.

Comment: i do not think that oncreate is called if only db version is changed, correct me if i am wrong, @fluffyBatman

Comment: Tanx a lot @ZakiPathan n all its solves my problem. Now I want to know I want to call webservice only when new updation or new record inserted. How can In do

Comment: @Nilabja Changing db version invokes `onUpgrade()` method where by default most people drop the existing db and call `onCreate()` to recreate the schema. For a live app, this ain't the scenario though.

Comment: If this helps you @MukeshMishra please mark this as a correct answer so others getting help from this. Happy to help you :) :) :)

Comment: @MukeshMishra and please do upvote too. Thnaks alot ;) ;)